# Using MergeSort to sort data structured in Person class based on object attributes (DRY)

Tags: python, classes

I am working on a program that sorts data using mergesort. I implemented functions to 'Person' class to make it comparable, sortable, subscriptable, iterable, and castable (to float, int, and string). I want to define everything once that no code is repeated - i.e. have D.R.Y. code. Did I implement some functionality (for example magic method) twice?

Are there any specific locations that can be shorter? and keep all functionalities at the same time? If so, suggest a change in a specific line.

```
class Person():
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._height = height
        self._weight = weight


    #def __len__(self):
        #return len(self.data)



    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self._name}, {self._age} years, {self._height} cm, {self._weight} kg\n"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) == (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) < (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) <= (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) > (other._age, other._height, other._weight)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) >= (other._age, other._height, other._weight)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._name}, {self._age} years, {self._height} cm, {self._weight} kg"

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self._name
        elif index == 1:
            return self._age
        elif index == 2:
            return self._weight
        elif index == 3:
            return self._height
        else:
            raise IndexError("Index out of range")

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self._age)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self._age)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return (self._name, self._age, self._weight, self._height)

    def to_list(self):
        return [self._name, self._age, self._weight, self._height]
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
    def get_height(self):
        return self._height
    def get_weight(self):
        return self._weight




def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
    
    person_objects = [(Person(np.random.choice(NAMES), np.random.randint(18, 101), np.random.randint(150, 201), np.random.randint(45, 101))) for _ in range(n)]
    #print("po: ",person_objects[0])
    x=Person()
    if sort_key == 'name':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_name())
    elif sort_key == 'age':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_age())
    elif sort_key == 'height':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_height())
    elif sort_key == 'weight':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_weight())
    else:
        return mergesort(person_objects)

# Example usage:
sorted_persons_by_name = create_persons_list(sort_key='name')
sorted_persons_by_age = create_persons_list(sort_key='age')
sorted_persons_by_height = create_persons_list(sort_key='height')
sorted_persons_by_weight = create_persons_list(sort_key='weight')


print("Sorted by height (default): \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_height)
print("Sorted by name: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_name)
print("Sorted by age: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_age)
print("Sorted by weight: \n")
print(sorted_persons_by_weight)
print("No key arg:  ", create_persons_list())
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/288780/revisions#rev-body-03d14f29-6053-46a7-acf4-07a8a8440a05) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

You can reduce the amount of code:

- Throw away `get_` methods, just use `.name` not `.get_name()`
- Throw away `to_tuple` and `to_list` by implementing `__len__` to make the class iterable.
- Throw away `__init__` and `__repr__` by using `dataclasses`.

  `__str__` can stay because your format is more 'str-like' than `dataclasses`'s generated `__repr__`.
- Throw away `__eq__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, and `__ge__` by using the `eq` and `order` options available in `dataclasses`.

  We will also need to tell `dataclasses` `name` should not be used in any of the comparison operators.

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass(eq=True, order=True)
class Person:
    name: str = dataclasses.field(compare=False)
    age: int
    height: int
    weight: int

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.age} years, {self.height} cm, {self.weight} kg"

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(dataclasses.fields(self))

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> str | int:
        return getattr(self, dataclasses.fields(self)[index].name)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.age)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.age)


FOO = Person("foo", 1, 1, 1)
BAR = Person("bar", 2, 2, 2)

print(FOO)
print(repr(FOO))
print(FOO == BAR)
print(FOO < BAR)
print(FOO <= BAR)
print(FOO > BAR)
print(FOO >= BAR)
print(FOO[0])
print(int(FOO))
print(float(FOO))
print(tuple(FOO))
print(list(FOO))
```

I would then urge you to remove `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__int__`, `__float__`, and `order=True` as I see no reason to make a person an iterable, a number, or ordered.

Comment: Alternatively, if the tuple-like behaviour of the `Person` class is something you really want, consider using a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple).

Comment: @Jasmijn If the situations needs tuple/iterable you are 100% correct. If you write an answer you can get reputation for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

`age` is a poor choice of attribute, as it is constantly changing over the lifetime of the data (which might be many years in a long-running server, or if persisted to a database).

It's better to store *birth date*, and compute the age when it's needed.

Comment: I think this is not justified without knowing more about what the class is being used for. Not every program has to keep data valid over the course of months or years, and among short-running programs there are contexts where collecting a birth date is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

1. The comparison dunder methods are not required for sorting `Person` by `name`, `age`, `height` or `weight`. It also leads to confusing behavior as semantically `Person` is not inherently sortable.
2. Not sure why dunder methods for conversion to `int` and `float`. Why should casting a `Person` to `int` even be permitted in the first place? This also has potential to confuse readers of your code.
3. Same with `to_list`, `to_tuple` etc.
4. Consider using `dataclasses` to get `__repr__` and `__str__` for free.

Your `Person` class can be as simple as:

```
@dataclass
class Person():
    
    name : str
    age : int
    height : float
    weight : float
```

Answer (score 2):

## type annotation

```
def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
```

Maybe you *need* that particular function name?
But I don't think so.
Prefer:

```
def create_persons(n: int = 10, sort_key: str = "height") -> list[Person]:
```

Better yet, us what you just created, like `def create_graduating_class`.

The annotation is meaningful to humans, to IDEs, and to `mypy`.

```
    person_objects = [
        (
            Person(
                np.random.choice(NAMES),
                np.random.randint(18, 101),
                np.random.randint(150, 201),
                np.random.randint(45, 101),
            )
        )
        for _ in range(n)
    ]
```

In python, *everything* is an object.
So that suffix isn't helpful.
Prefer to just assign `persons = ...`.
(Maybe `people`? Whatever.)

## useless getters

```
    def get_name( ...
    def get_age( ...
    def get_height( ...
    def get_weight( ...
```

This isn't java.
We're all adults here.

We only need the getters because you declared
four attributes as `_private`.
Consider ditching the getters and defining four public attributes in the ctor:

```
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
```

If you need to prohibit mutation,
such as `self._age += 1` on someone's birthday, fine.
First document that immutability requirement so we understand the "why",
then use a
[property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)
decorator in the usual way.
Then you will get an appropriate diagnostic:

```
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    ...
p = Person()
p.age += 1  # --> AttributeError: property 'age' of 'Person' object has no setter
```

But why are we writing tedious code like this at all?
Prefer `@dataclass`, or an immutable `namedtuple`.

## unused local

```
def create_persons_list( ...
    ...
    x = Person()
```

Please delete `x`.

1. It isn't used.
2. The *other* `x` down within `lambda` scope risks being confused with it.

## attrgetter

```
    elif sort_key == 'weight':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.get_weight())
```

A lambda is an unnamed (anonymous) function.

But you wrote one for something that already *has* a name:
[attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter).

Prefer `key=attrgetter(sort_key)`, without all those copy-n-pasted `else` clauses.
Or perhaps `key=attrgetter(f"_{sort_key}")`.
Or perhaps even [methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):
`key=methodcaller(f"get_{sort_key}")`.

## total_order

```
    def __lt__(self, other):
        ...
    def __le__(self, other):
        ...
    def __gt__(self, other):
        ...
    def __ge__(self, other):
```

Write just *one* of those, and let the
[@total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)
decorator sweat the details on the rest.

## representation dunders

The `__str__` method is nice enough.

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
up `__repr__` with:

```
        return f"{self}\n"
```

But wait!
Consider altering the text it returns.
Maybe `repr(person)` is working adequately for you?
It is *supposed* to be a string that when pasted into the REPL
will produce a new `Person` object.
Try it with some `namedtuple` you define, to see the difference.

Similarly, DRY up `to_list` with:

```
    return list(self.to_tuple())
```

Or consider deleting that method,
as we see no calling code which motivates it.
In python, we use `list` for arbitrary number of "same" kind of thing,
and we use `tuple` for fixed-length collection of different things
where the meaning of an item is dictated by its position.
For example in an (x, y) `Point`, both the `[0]` and `[1]` indexes
are for floats, but the *meanings* of those floats are entirely different.
Your `to_tuple` method does exactly the Right Thing in this regard.

## notion of equality

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._age, self._height, self._weight) == (other._age, other._height, other._weight)
```

Consider

```
alice = Person("Alice", 10, 135, 30)
bob   = Person("Bob",   10, 135, 30)
alice == bob
```

That seems a weird enough notion of "equals" that it *at least*
warrants a """docstring""" explaining the business domain
where that makes sense.

I am sad we didn't go with a `namedtuple`.
If you require business logic that offers surprisingly different behavior
from the familiar example of a tuple, fine.
But at least document it.

Answer (score 1):

> make it comparable, sortable, subscriptable, iterable, and castable (to float, int, and string). I want to define everything once that no code is repeated - i.e. have D.R.Y. code.

I would be inclined to *not* give your class any of those properties (comparable, sortable, subscriptable, iterable, or castable).  Since you seem to like initialisms, omitting those features would be more consistent with the ["Keep it simple, Stupid" (KISS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and ["You aren't going to need it" (YAGNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles.  Somewhat also with the [Principle of least astonishment (POLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Consider:

- What use do you imagine anyone might have for converting a `Person` to an `int`?  Why do you suppose that the `int` they would want is the `age` property, as opposed to `height` or `weight`, or something altogether different such as a hash code?  Why wouldn't they just say what they mean by reading the property value they want?
- Why do you suppose anyone would want to access the properties by index, or to iterate over their values?  That would be nonsense for anyone who doesn't already know that the object is a `Person`, so as to be able to map indices to particular properties, and if you *do* know it's a person then accessing its properties directly, by name, would be more Pythonic.
- Why do you think the particular sort and comparison order you are implementing is so natural that it should be baked into the class?  It's better not to have a built-in order at all than to have an arbitrary one.  And a consequence of choosing the particular order you have done is a rather surprising implementation of `__eq__()`.  In no way would I expect that two instances could be considered equal when their names differ, so this violates the POLA.
- Do you genuinely imagine that obtaining a list or tuple of an instance's properties are things that users of this class are so likely to want that it makes sense to build that into your class?  And if so, that the order you have chosen will be suitable?

The DRY principle does not imply that you need to provide every functionality that you imagine someone else might want.  That's a losing proposition, because your imagination is not nearly good enough (mine either). DRY is about minimizing repetition in *your own* code, mainly by good design and especially by factoring common code into reusable units to avoid repeating it.

In general, choose class features that yield a coherent result that is as natural and intuitive as possible to use.  Within those guidelines, ensure that it has all the features that *you* need it to have, preferably from a holistic viewpoint of the overall design of the module, package, or application.  ***Then stop***.

There are a couple of DRYness consideration in the code that would leave, however:

- The `if` / `elif` / `else` chain in your `create_persons_list()` function is a bit wet because the `mergesort()` call is repeated with only changes in the specified key.
- you could dry out your code a little by removing its `__str__` method.  The default `__str__()` defers to `__repr__()`, which in your code produces the same output (plus a newline, which should be removed anyway).  But really, `__repr__()` serves a different purpose than `__str__()`, the former is meant to be informative for development and debugging, whereas the latter, if it differs, is meant to be informative to human users.  If you want the user-readable `__str__()`, then a better resolution might be to make `__repr__()` emit something more conventional.

If you left both `to_list()` and `to_tuple()` then that would present another dryness issue.  You have repeated the element order in those functions, and it would be DRYer (and prevent them falling out of sync) to implement one in terms of the other.

---

Additionally, it is not conventional or Pythonic to endow classes with `get_foo()` property getter methods (and omitting setter methods does not prevent modifying instances' properties). Objects properties are Pythonically accessed directly by their names, *e.g.* `a_person.age`, `another.height`.

---

After all that dross is polished off, this is what's left of `Person`:

```
class Person():
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person('{self.name}', {self.age}, {self.height}, {self.weight})"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.age} years, {self.height} cm, {self.weight} kg"
```

Only a few minor modifications are required elsewhere in your code:

```
def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
    
    person_objects = [(Person(np.random.choice(NAMES), np.random.randint(18, 101), np.random.randint(150, 201), np.random.randint(45, 101))) for _ in range(n)]

    if sort_key == 'name':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.name)
    elif sort_key == 'age':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.age)
    elif sort_key == 'height':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.height)
    elif sort_key == 'weight':
        return mergesort(person_objects, key=lambda x: x.weight)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'unknown sort key: {key}')
```

... but if you really want to DRY that out, then something more like this would be better in that regard:

```
def create_persons_list(n=10, sort_key='height'):
    # Note: using this dict is dryer, but one could get dryer still
    # by leveraging getattr()
    keys = {
      'name':   lambda x: x.name,
      'age':    lambda x: x.age,
      'height': lambda x: x.height,
      'weight': lambda x: x.weight
    }
    
    person_objects = [(Person(np.random.choice(NAMES), np.random.randint(18, 101), np.random.randint(150, 201), np.random.randint(45, 101))) for _ in range(n)]

    # Note: this will raise a KeyError if the specified key is not among those
    # supported.  That creates a bit of a pun on the word "key", and it might
    # be advisable to rescue it to raise a ValueError (or some other) instead 
    return mergesort(person_objects, key=keys[sort_key])
```